# Importing a class in Groovy

Tags: groovy

I'm trying to import another class in groovy, but to no sucess so far. I've tried to run this example:

http://www.chatsiri.com/?q=node/163

didn't work.

Caught: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: readData

Answer (score 2):

There is a lot of typos in the Code, and it does not follow the Convention for the java classes like (and the article is from 2007):

- Class instead of class
- Class name starting with lowercase
- printIn? instead of println
- System.In.readString()??? Not in the actual [Groovy JDK](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/io/InputStream.html)

Anyways, just creating new classes Foo and Bar to corraborate what the blog is saying.....

File Bar.groovy

```
class Bar{
    def print(){
        println "Bar"
    }

    def add(a, b){
        return a+b;
    }

}
```

File Foo.groovy

```
def b = new Bar()
b.print()
println b.add(1,2)
```

Runing

```
>groovy Foo.groovy
Bar
3
```

Comment: I had change most of that stuff. Anyway, your code works for me (though I'm using grails, and it works on the console and not on STS, but that's irrelevant)
Thanks!